# Print long webpages with Sketch

Tags: print-design, sketch-app

I'd like to print a very long webpage I designed on Sketch. But after I export the artboard as PDF and print it, the whole page fits into one A4, making it impossible to read.

Is there a way to print the artboard on A4 portrait without scaling it to fit WITHOUT using Illustrator or Photoshop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two approaches to solve your issue.
The first one is to slice your artboard so each slice fits exactly to A4 paper by width and height.
The second one is usefull when you already have the pdf (Preview crop approach).

**Slice approach**

For instance we have a very long design in Sketch:

[image]

Create Slice with the same width as your design and the height calcualated by this formula: height = width * 1.414 (due to A4 paper size proportion is 297mm(width) / 210mm(height) = 1.414). In my case 1033*1.414=1461. 
Place slice at the top left corner or your design, named it something like A4-page 1.
You can export this slice to pdf, and it will print exactly on A4 paper with proper propotions.

[image]

After you can duplicate this Slice, and move it down by changing Y position, I simply put slice height to y field and it places exactly below the first slice:

[image]

By this way you can add as much slices as you want. Just place them below each other:
[image]

Export each slice to separate pdf and print them, they will fit A4 paper properly.

**Preview crop approach**

Open your long design pdf in Preview.
[image]

Press cmd + I to show Inspector view. Select ruler tab:
[image]

Select the area with x=0, y=0 position. Width the same as design, height is calculated by formula shown above 1033*1.414=1461.
[image]

Then press Crop button, the info window will appear press ok:
   [image]

And you have the part of your pdf which fits A4 paper, you can save it or print:
[image]

Changing Y position of you Crop selection you can make several A4 pdfs.
Additional info for pdf slicing: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12305/split-a-single-page-pdf-into-multiple-pages

Comment: hey @zholdas, I've tried that but when I select FIll Entire Paper it just prints what's on the preview and it stops.

Comment: @user2706712 Updated my answer above. Sketch and Preview approaches explained.